# How to Disassemble an object creation in Python?

Tags: python

Having a class like this:

```
class Spam(object):
   def __init__(self, name=''):
      self.name = name

eggs = Spam('systempuntoout')
```

using `dis`, is it possible to see how an instance of a class and the respective hex Identity are created?

Comment: I've tried of course before posting , and i thought it was not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it isn't obvious from the output, which is at the level of Python bytecode, e.g.:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def f(x): return x * x
... 
>>> dis.dis(Foo)
Disassembly of f:
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

It doesn't take much to figure out what Foo.f is doing from the above dump, but it quickly becomes unreadable to most people as the size of the code grows.

Comment: Sorry Marcelo but i don't understand your answer, does it anwser my question in any way :)?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question. The `dis` module shows you the bytecode of compiled functions and methods. If you call `dis.dis(Spam)` with your class, you will see the bytecode implementation of your init method. It this what you want, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Yes, i was talking about dis.dis(Spam) thanks.Is it possible to see when object ID is created?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the object's id is simply its memory address cast as an integer.